# Cython: Are there differences between `cdef public: void f()` and `cdef public: cdef void f()`

Tags: python, syntax, header, cython

A function in .pxd file and be define this way:

```
cdef public:
    void f()
```

Or this way:

```
cdef public:
    cdef void f()
```

Both cases are compiled fine without errors. I wonder about the differences between those two and which one is the real C function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested it out myself, the result is: They're exactly the same.

I've checked out *.h, *_api.h, *.c, *.cpp output files of Cython transpiler for a test module with the definitions stated in the question and they equal in every byte.

Conclusion: The 2nd cdef is redundant.